# Cannot create property 'importer' on string 'scss/bootstrap.scss'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, parceljs

During Parcel compilation, this error occurs:

`Cannot create property 'importer' on string 'scss/bootstrap.scss'`

My `app.css` file:

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import './styles/style.scss';
@import './styles/plugins/plugins.scss';
@import './styles/plugins/plugins.css';
@import './styles/loader.scss';
@import './styles/custom.css';
```

Why is Parcel not recognizing the correct bootstrap SCSS?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this [a bug in parcel](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7163) caused by the the way that `@parcel/transformer-sass` goes looking for configuration files that might be located in your project. One of the sources of configuration is the `sass` field in `package.json` (see [code](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/blob/daed0c3fa3c1c5c52ab3e3a98f5494bfc3be06c4/packages/transformers/sass/src/SassTransformer.js#L17)). For some reason, bootstrap's `package.json` has `"sass": "scss/bootstrap.scss"` (see [code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/5771fcc4a9aed00057728988250269cfe0c9aa03/package.json#L84)), which isn't the format parcel is expecting, so it chokes.

I found a workaround while we work on a fix - if the type of the file that contains the `@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';` line is `.scss` instead of `.css`, it should work.